# Abort trap 6 upon function return with dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, sigabrt, dynamic-allocation

I have trouble debugging an "Abort trap 6" error in C using Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) on OS X Mavericks. The goal is to construct a data structure `word2class` which contains for each word in a vocabulary of `num_words` words an array of class ids to which that word belongs (arbitrary, but for example: Noun, Verb, ..., as integer ids) **and also its inverse**, `class2word` which contains for each class `0 <= class < num_class` an array of the words it contains.

To do this, I am maintaining global arrays of pointers to arrays of long longs. The forwards data structure (`word2class`) and backwards data structure (`class2words`) are constructed in the same manner, call this A for now. Both A and each array pointed to by each element A[i] is dynamically allocated. At construction we know the maximum number of elements that A may contain (`num_words` or `num_class`). A is constructed by reading index,id pairs from a file (`index` is a word id, and `id` is a class id). Each `id` should be inserted into the array pointed to by `A[index]`. Words that belong to more than one class are stored as a separate line for each class id (e.g. `0<tab>0<newline>0<tab>1`).  During construction, I maintain an array of the current maximum size of each array `A_max_size[i]`, and the current number of elements in each array `A_cur_size[i]`, and lazily realloc() each *A[i] if it gets too small. I amortize memory allocation costs by resizing A[i] by factor 2 whenever it gets too small. Below is the actual relevant parts of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// global arrays of pointers to long longs
long long **word2class = NULL, **class2word = NULL;
// bounds for each array pointed to by word2class[i] / class2word[j]
long long *w2c_cur_size = NULL, *c2w_cur_size = NULL;
// max number of words, passed as first argument argv[1]
// max number of classes, read from file
long long num_words, num_classes = 0;

void AllocateAndInsert(long long **A, long long *A_cur_size, long long *A_max_size,
    long long index, long long item) {
 if (A == NULL || A_cur_size == NULL || A_max_size == NULL) {
  printf("NULL pointer passed.\n"); exit(1);
 }
 // Check if A[index] is big enough, realloc if needed
 if (A_cur_size[index] + 1 >= A_max_size[index]) {
   if (A_max_size[index] == 0) A_max_size[index] = 1;
   else A_max_size[index] *= 2;  // amortize memory allocation
   // dynamically allocate a large enough array of long longs
   A[index] = (long long*)realloc(A[index], A_max_size[index] * sizeof(long long));
   if (A[index] == NULL) { 
    printf("(Re)allocation error.\n");
    exit(1);
   }
 }
 // insert item at end of array pointed to by A[index]
 A[index][A_cur_size[index]] = item;
 A_cur_size[index]++;
}

void PrintDS(long long **A, long long max_index, long long *A_size) {
 int i, j;
 for (i = 0; i < max_index; i++) {
  printf("Index %d:\n", i);
  for (int j = 0; j < A_size[i]; j++) {
   printf("%lld ", A[i][j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
 }
}

void BuildDataStruct(char *fname) {
 FILE *fin = fopen(fname, "r");
 long long index, id;
 long long *w2c_max_size, *c2w_max_size;     // temp variables used during construction

 if (fin == NULL) {
   printf("Error opening file.\n"); 
   exit(1);
 }

 // read max number of classes as first line from file
 if (fscanf(fin, "%lld\n", &num_classes) != 1) { 
   printf("File format error.\n"); 
   exit(1); 
 }
 // word2class
 w2c_max_size = calloc(num_words, sizeof(long long));  // initialized to 0s
 w2c_cur_size = calloc(num_words, sizeof(long long));
 word2class = calloc(num_words, sizeof(long long *));
 // class2word
 c2w_max_size = calloc(num_classes, sizeof(long long));
 c2w_cur_size = calloc(num_classes, sizeof(long long));
 class2word = calloc(num_classes, sizeof(long long *));
 if (w2c_max_size == NULL || w2c_cur_size == NULL || word2class == NULL ||
     c2w_max_size == NULL || c2w_cur_size == NULL || class2word == NULL) {
  printf("Allocation error.\n"); 
  exit(1);
 }

 while (!feof(fin)) {
   if (fscanf(fin, "%lld\t%lld\n", &index, &id) != 2) {
     printf("Format error.\n");
     exit(1);
   }
   if (index < 0 || index >= num_words || id < 0 || id >= num_classes) { 
    printf("Bounds error.\n"); 
    exit(1); 
   }
   AllocateAndInsert(word2class, w2c_cur_size, w2c_max_size, index, id);
   AllocateAndInsert(class2word, c2w_cur_size, c2w_max_size, id, index);
 }

 fclose(fin);
 free(w2c_max_size);
 free(c2w_max_size);
 // DATA STRUCTURE PRINTS FINE HERE
 PrintDS(word2class, num_words, w2c_cur_size);
 PrintDS(class2word, num_classes, c2w_cur_size);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc <= 2) { 
    printf("Usage: %s num_words word2class_file\n", argv[0]); 
    exit(1); 
  }
  num_words = atoi(argv[1]);
  BuildDataStruct(argv[2]);
  // <-- 'Abort Trap 6' RAISED HERE
  return 0;
}
```

For those interested, test data can be generated using the following script as `python script.py num_words max_class_id max_class_per_word out_file` and consumed using the above C code as `./build_ds num_words out_file`:

```
import sys
from random import sample, randint

num_words = int(sys.argv[1])
max_class_id = int(sys.argv[2])
max_class_per_word = int(sys.argv[3])
f = open(sys.argv[4], 'w')

f.write("%d\n" % (max_class_id,))
for w in xrange(num_words):
    num_classes = randint(1, max_class_per_word)
    classes = sample(xrange(max_class_id), num_classes)
    for c in classes:
        f.write("%d\t%d\n" % (w, c))

f.close()
```

**This code works (even on the 'real' data), however, once I use this exact code as part of a larger application, the program terminates with the cryptic "Abort trap 6" error.** 
`BuildDataStruct()` is called from another function and seems to work fine for the construction part. One can print out both data structures **before returning** from `BuildDataStruct()` with no problem. However, immediately after the function returns the error is generated.

From reading various other answers, the `Abort Trap: 6` error seems to be raised on OS X when a buffer is overwritten. However, I have added checks on `index` to ensure that does not happen, so I am not sure what else might be the problem? Am I perhaps overwriting the stack somehow? Does anyone have any ideas where or how I can start hunting for the issue?

Comment: Is this the actual code that is causing problems?  Because 1) It doesn't compile; 2) You never use the `id` after reading it; 3) you never write any values into the `cur_size` array.  Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: @dbc No this was meant to be a minimal working example. But I have updated my question to show the actual code I am using, and to explain what I'm trying to accomplish with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem was actually with the fscanf() line for reading the word and class**. I made one simplification to the code I posted: In my actual code, word2class is stored as a `<word_str> <tab> <class_int> <newline>` entry per line. I.e. I store words as strings instead of long long ids. I then read the word into a `char word[MAX_STRING]` buffer and then lookup its long long word_id.

The problem was that some words were longer than MAX_STRING-1, which overwrites the null-terminated string `word`, which caused a **seg fault**. The problem was further compounded since I used the `-Ofast` optimization flag, which somehow changed the segfault error to the `Abort trap 6` error. Once I compiled without the optimization flag, I realized it was a seg-fault, which I was able to trace to the fscanf() function using `valgrind` and `gdb`.

The solution was to **add a maximum length to the %s fscanf format string**, as follows:

```
#define MAX_STRING 100
#define MAX_STRING_S "99"  // careful not to overwrite terminating null

...

// in BuildDataStruct()
char word[MAX_STRING];
if (fscanf(fin, "%" MAX_STRING_S "s\t%lld", word, &class) != 2) {
  printf("Format error in class_file\n");
  // continue or exit
}
```

This code now correctly identifies the formatting error in class_file, and furthermore works correctly as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. It doesn't compile because several `{`'s are commented out:

   ```
   if (A == NULL) { // handle allocation error }
   ```

   I'll assume this is just a transcription error.
2. You don't check the return of [`fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) to make sure that two arguments were read.  Any syntax errors in the file could lead to corruption.
3. You read two fields from each line, `index` and `id`, but only use the first.  The second is ignored.  Also, you never set any value in the `cur_size` array so it's always going to be zero in your code.

   So, I'm going to make an assumption: `index` is the index in the outer array `A`, and `id` is an index into the corresponding inner array, i.e. you want to be able to allocate large enough arrays that `A[index][id]` exists.
4. Given my assumption, there is an algorithm problem: you double the size `max_size[index]` if it is smaller than `cur_size[index]` -- but don't consider that `cur_size[index]` might be more than twice as large.  You need to double the size *and* ensure it's larger than `id+1`.
5. You should keep around the `cur_size` array so you can check for out-of-bounds indexing later.
6. `calloc` fills memory with zeros, but [`realloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) leaves the value of the newly allocated portion indeterminate.
7. On my platform, `long long` is 64 bits but `calloc` and `realloc` accept `size_t` for the first argument, so I'm seeing several "conversion from '__int64' to 'size_t', possible loss of data" errors.  You should check to make sure that `calloc` takes a `long long` on your platform.

So, a fix for problems 1-6 might look like:

```
long long **A = NULL; // global array of pointers to long longs
long long *A_cur_size_array = NULL;

long long N = 1000; // for exax1mple

// If your platform has a predefined version of "max", use it instead.
static long long max_long_long(long long a, long long b)
{
    // If your platform has a predefined version of "max", use it instead.
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

void construct_A(char *fname) 
{
    FILE *fin = fopen(fname, "r");
    long long index, id;
    long long *max_size_array;

    A_cur_size_array = calloc(N, sizeof(int));
    A = calloc(N, sizeof(long long *));
    max_size_array = calloc(N, sizeof(int));   // init to 0

    if (A == NULL || max_size_array == NULL || A_cur_size_array == NULL) 
    { 
        // handle allocation error 
    }
    while (!feof(fin)) 
    {
        if (fscanf(fin, "%lld\t%lld\n", &index, &id) != 2)
        {
            printf("File format error.\n"); 
            exit(1); 
        }
        if (index < 0 || index >= N) 
        { 
            printf("BOUNDS ERROR\n"); 
            exit(1); 
        }
        if (id < 0)
        {
            printf("BOUNDS ERROR\n"); 
            exit(1); 
        }
        if (id >= A_cur_size_array[index])
        {
            A_cur_size_array[index] = id + 1;
            if (A_cur_size_array[index] >= max_size_array[index]) 
            {
                long long new_max_size = max_long_long(id + 1, 2 * max_size_array[index]);
                long long i;
                // dynamically allocate a large enough array of long longs
                A[index] = (long long*)realloc(A[index], new_max_size * sizeof(long long));
                if (A[index] == NULL) 
                { 
                    // handle allocation error 
                }
                for (i = max_size_array[index]; i < new_max_size; i++)
                    A[index][i] = 0;
                max_size_array[index] = new_max_size;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fin);
    free(max_size_array);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You raise interesting points. I have updated my code to include the error checks and updated the question with more detail. Note that your assumption is incorrect: id is simply appended to the array pointed to by A[index], and therefore I don't need to perform the second bounds check (since A_max_size[i] is guaranteed to always be >= A_cur_size[i]).

Comment: One more point: although realloc() doesn't zero the newly-allocated memory, this has no effect since I am only reading memory that has been written to (i.e. inside A_cur_size[i] in my updated code).